# Using EM units in a responsive build for desktop, tablet and mobile views but only on certain elements

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design, font-size

I am currently building a responsive site and have used EM units for font-size, line-height, padding etc in order to make the resizing task smoother when moving from desktop to tablet to mobile. So at the moment my body font is set at `100%` for desktop, then I thought that I would drop this `%` when in tablet and then again in mobile. What my problem is though is what if I dont want everything in mobile to resize from `100% to 80%`? Maybe I only want this to happen to the main body content and headings, whats the best way to just resize some things? I've tried for example changing the main header font sizes inside my mobile breakpoint to be % but this doesnt seem to be correct. I just want to better understand the best approach when it comes to resizing fonts for each view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just target the tags used.

Desktop

```
h1 { font-size:100%; }
```

mobile

```
h1 { font-size:80%; }
```

You just need to wrap each part of the css in media queries.

If you want more specific try added classes to the p tags of heading if there are certain ones you want resized.

Desktop

```
h1, h1.alt { width:100%; }
```

Mobile

```
h1.alt { width: 70%; }
```

The above would only change H1's with the class alt applied to them.